# Como criar um calendário em C?

Tags: c, data, calendar, calendario

Preciso escrever o calendário no seguinte formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou testando com 2 meses mas não consigo manter o alinhamento lateral.
Meu código está dessa forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i; //mes
int j; //dia
int cont = 0; //quebra linha
int ano, mes, dia, bis;
int g, c, x, z, e, d, n;
int mesDias[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
char *months[]=
{
    "Janeiro",
    "Fevereiro",
    "Marco",
    "Abril",
    "Maio\t",
    "Junho",
    "Julho",
    "Agosto",
    "Setembro",
    "Outubro",
    "Novembro",
    "Dezembro"
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Digite o ano: ");
    scanf("%d", &ano);
    
    
    //P A S C O A
    
    g = (ano % 19) + 1; //resto inteiro - AUREO
    c = (ano / 100) + 1; //SECULO
    x = ((3 * c) / 4) - 12; //CORRECAO 1
    z = (((8 * c) + 5) / 25) - 5; //CORRECAO 2
    e = ((11 * g) + 20 + z - x) % 30; //resto inteiro
    
    //EPACTA
    if(e == 25 && g > 11){
        e++;
    }
    else if(e == 24){
        e++;
    }
    
    //LUA CHEIA
    n = 44 - e; 
    if(n < 21){
        n += 30;
    }
    
    //DOMINGO DE PASCOA
    d = ((5 * ano) / 4) - (x + 10);
    
    
    //DIA/MES PASCOA
    n = (n + 7) - ((d + n) % 7);
    
    if(n > 31){
        n = n - 31;
        printf("Pascoa: %d de abril", n);
        mes = 4;
    }
    else{
        printf("Pascoa: %d de marco", n);
        mes = 3;
    }
    
    // B I S S E X T O
    
    if (ano % 4 == 0 && (ano % 400 == 0 || ano % 100 != 0)) {
        printf("\nAno bissexto.");
        bis = 1;
        mesDias[1] = 29;
    }
    else {
        printf("\nAno nao bissexto.");
        bis = 0;
    }
    
    
    //1   D E    J A N E I R O
    if(mes == 4){
        dia = 8 - ((n + bis + 31 + 28 + 31 ) % 7) ; 
    }
    else if(mes == 3){
        dia = 8 - ((n + bis + 31 + 28) % 7) ;
    }
    if(dia > 6) dia -= 7;
    
    dia++;
    
    if(dia == 1){
        printf("\n1 de jan: domingo\n");
    }else if(dia == 2){
        printf("\n1 de jan: segunda\n");
    }else if(dia == 3){
        printf("\n1 de jan: terca\n");
    }else if(dia == 4){
        printf("\n1 de jan: quarta\n");
    }else if(dia == 5){
        printf("\n1 de jan: quinta\n");
    }else if(dia == 6){
        printf("\n1 de jan: sexta\n");
    }else if(dia == 7){
        printf("\n1 de jan: sabado\n");
    }
    
    printf("\n\n");
    
    
    /*CALENDÁRIO*/
    
    printf("Calendario do ano %d\n", ano);
    
    printf("|-----------------------------|\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        
    printf("|%s\t\t      |\n", months[i]);
    printf("| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |\n");
    printf("|");
    printf("  ");
    
    /*pular dias vazios*/
    if(i == 0){
        for ( j = 0; j < dia - 1; j++ ){
            printf("--  ");
            cont++;
        }
    }else{
        if(dia != 0){
            for ( j = 0; j < dia - 1; j++ ){
                printf("--  ");
                cont++;
            }
        }else{
            for ( j = -1; j < dia - 1; j++ ){
                printf("--  ");
                cont++;
            }   
        }
        
        printf("--  ");
    }
    
    
    /*escrever meses do dia*/
    for(j = 1; j < mesDias[i] + 1; j++){
        
        if(j <= 9){
            
            if(cont >= 6){
                printf(" %d |\n|  ", j);
                cont = 0;
            }else{
                printf(" %d  ", j);
                cont++;
            }


        }else{
            if(j == 10){
                printf("%d", j);
                cont++;
            }else{
                printf("  %d", j);
                cont++;
            }           
            
            if(cont > 6){
                printf(" |\n|");
                cont = 0;
            }
        }
        
        if(cont > 6){
            printf("\n|  ");
            cont = 0;
        }
        
    }
    printf("\n");
    dia = cont;
    
    printf("\ndia: %d\n", dia);
    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, para exibir o nome do mês com alinhamento, não use `\t`. Aproveite as opções que [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) te dá:

```
char *months[]=
{
    "Janeiro",
    "Fevereiro",
    "Marco",
    "Abril",
    "Maio", // <-- removi o \t daqui
    "Junho",
    "Julho",
    "Agosto",
    "Setembro",
    "Outubro",
    "Novembro",
    "Dezembro"
};

...
printf("|%-29s|\n", months[i]);
```

O formato `%-29s` diz para alinhar à esquerda, ocupando 29 posições (as posições que não são usadas são preenchidas com espaços). Assim você não fica dependendo de `\t` e outras gambiarras, o `printf` já cuida do alinhamento para você.

---

Já para imprimir os dias do mês, você está complicando a lógica à toa. Dá para fazer assim:

```
printf("Calendario do ano %d\n", ano);
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) { // para cada mês
    int diaDaSemana = 0; // começa sempre a imprimir do domingo

    printf("|-----------------------------|\n");
    printf("|%-29s|\n", months[i]);
    printf("|-----------------------------|\n");
    printf("| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |\n");
    printf("|");

    int linhasImpressas = 1; // quantidade de linhas que já foram impressas

    // pular dias vazios do início do mês
    for (j = 0; j < dia - 1; j++) {
        printf("  --");
        diaDaSemana++;
    }

    // dias do mês
    for (int diaDoMes = 1; diaDoMes <= mesDias[i]; diaDoMes++) {
        printf("  %02d", diaDoMes);
        if (diaDaSemana >= 6) { // chegou no sábado, começar nova linha
            printf(" |\n|");
            diaDaSemana = 0;
            linhasImpressas++;
        } else diaDaSemana++;
    }
    dia = diaDaSemana + 1;

    if (linhasImpressas == 5) {    
        // preencher o que falta na quinta linha
        while (diaDaSemana <= 6) {
            printf("  --");
            diaDaSemana++;
        }
        // imprimir a sexta linha
        printf(" |\n|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |\n");
    } else if (linhasImpressas == 6) {
        // preencher o que falta na sexta linha
        for (int x = dia - 1; x <= 6; x++)
            printf("  --");
        printf(" |\n");
    }
}
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu preencho os dias vazios do início do mês. Depois vou preenchendo os dias, usando o formato `%02d` que imprime o número com um zero à esquerda caso necessário.

Depois eu verifico se estou na quinta ou sexta linha (pelo que entendi, todos os meses devem ter 6 linhas), e preencho o que estiver faltando em cada caso.

Exemplo de saída para o ano 2020:

```
Calendario do ano 2020
|-----------------------------|
|Janeiro                      |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  --  01  02  03  04 |
|  05  06  07  08  09  10  11 |
|  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 |
|  19  20  21  22  23  24  25 |
|  26  27  28  29  30  31  -- |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Fevereiro                    |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  01 |
|  02  03  04  05  06  07  08 |
|  09  10  11  12  13  14  15 |
|  16  17  18  19  20  21  22 |
|  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Marco                        |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  01  02  03  04  05  06  07 |
|  08  09  10  11  12  13  14 |
|  15  16  17  18  19  20  21 |
|  22  23  24  25  26  27  28 |
|  29  30  31  --  --  --  -- |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Abril                        |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  --  01  02  03  04 |
|  05  06  07  08  09  10  11 |
|  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 |
|  19  20  21  22  23  24  25 |
|  26  27  28  29  30  --  -- |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Maio                         |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  --  --  --  01  02 |
|  03  04  05  06  07  08  09 |
|  10  11  12  13  14  15  16 |
|  17  18  19  20  21  22  23 |
|  24  25  26  27  28  29  30 |
|  31  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Junho                        |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  01  02  03  04  05  06 |
|  07  08  09  10  11  12  13 |
|  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 |
|  21  22  23  24  25  26  27 |
|  28  29  30  --  --  --  -- |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Julho                        |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  --  01  02  03  04 |
|  05  06  07  08  09  10  11 |
|  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 |
|  19  20  21  22  23  24  25 |
|  26  27  28  29  30  31  -- |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Agosto                       |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  01 |
|  02  03  04  05  06  07  08 |
|  09  10  11  12  13  14  15 |
|  16  17  18  19  20  21  22 |
|  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 |
|  30  31  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Setembro                     |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  01  02  03  04  05 |
|  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 |
|  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 |
|  20  21  22  23  24  25  26 |
|  27  28  29  30  --  --  -- |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Outubro                      |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  --  --  01  02  03 |
|  04  05  06  07  08  09  10 |
|  11  12  13  14  15  16  17 |
|  18  19  20  21  22  23  24 |
|  25  26  27  28  29  30  31 |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Novembro                     |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  01  02  03  04  05  06  07 |
|  08  09  10  11  12  13  14 |
|  15  16  17  18  19  20  21 |
|  22  23  24  25  26  27  28 |
|  29  30  --  --  --  --  -- |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
|-----------------------------|
|Dezembro                     |
|-----------------------------|
| dom seg ter qua qui sex sab |
|  --  --  01  02  03  04  05 |
|  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 |
|  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 |
|  20  21  22  23  24  25  26 |
|  27  28  29  30  31  --  -- |
|  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- |
```

---

Claro que ainda dá para melhorar outras coisas, como dar nomes melhores para as variáveis. Em vez de `i` e `j`, poderia ser `mesAtual` e `diaDoMes`, ou algo assim, e a variável `dia` poderia ser algo como `primeiroDiaSemana` (ou algum outro nome que indique que ela se refere ao dia da semana correspondente ao primeiro dia do mês). Pode parecer besteira, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

O `for` que imprime os dias do mês também poderia ser:

```
for (int diaDoMes = 1; diaDoMes <= mesDias[i]; diaDoMes++) {
    printf("  %02d", diaDoMes);
    if (diaDaSemana == 6) {
        printf(" |\n|");
        linhasImpressas++;
    }
    diaDaSemana = (diaDaSemana + 1) % 7;
}
```

O [operador](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) `%` pega o resto da divisão. Então quando o valor de `diaDaSemana + 1` se torna 7, ele volta a valer zero (pois o resto da divisão de 7 por 7 é zero). Assim, a contagem volta para o valor inicial a cada 7 iterações. E o teste pode ser `diaDaSemana == 6` (como eu inicializo ela com zero no início do `for` mais externo, e sempre pego o resto da divisão por 7, eu sei que não será maior que 6).